# How to test the connectivity without using ICMP?

Tags: network-programming

In our system, we used to test the connectivity between different nodes using ICMP messages. But out of security concern, this keep alive mechanism is required to be banned by our customers. So we have to replace the ICMP message with some other protocol messages. Currently, our solution is using TCP. Obviously, this solution has at least 2 disadvantages:
1. failures occurred on one TCP connection don't necessarily mean the same thing happened to the others, and don't mean lower-layer connectivity(eg, IP) failures as well.
2. establishing a TCP connection and sending/receiving TCP message are quite time-consuming, which is another challenge to our existing connectivity testing schedule.

I'm wondering if there is any other solutions other than TCP that can meet our requirement.

Comment: What do you want to test exactly? what do you mean if the TCP fails you still may be connected?

Comment: on what systems you trying to do it? for the 1 disadvantage ... you don't have to close the server if an error on the connection occur, then none of the other connections have to disconnect because of this. for the 2 disadvantage ... i think this is how it has to be done to achieve stability then it worth

Comment: To Ali, our purpose is just to detect if the peer is still alive(ping-able)

Comment: To memosdp, our system is WindRiver linux. For the first disadvantage, the concern is: Even if the testing connection gets down, we are still unable to judge the connectivity status since other regular connection may remain good. So it can't achieve the goal as the original ICMP did.

Comment: banning ICMP has no improvement on security.

Comment: This strongly depends on system architecture. If you have access to all devices (monitored and monitoring) you can basically use any type of protocol (TCP and UDP could be only some possibilities). If you don't want to use TCP just use UDP (as keep-alive) and implement some simple service on monitored device that will respond to each UDP packet it will receive from your monitored device. No response = no connection. This will be quite lightweight and rather easy to implement and maintain.